# Are non-Apple Mac OS X / iOS software questions on topic? Is the FAQ outdated?

Tags: support

I'm confused. The FAQ says questions are on topic if they concern:

> - Apple hardware
> - Apple software
> - other Apple products or services

Why questions about software, which are not made by Apple, are seemingly accepted? (See e.g. the [software-recommendation](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software-recommendation) tag) Is the FAQ outdated?

Moreover, if the FAQ is outdated, what kind of OS X related questions could/should be asked on [Super User](https://superuser.com/)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [software-recommendation](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software-recommendation) tag means that someone is looking for software that works with Apple hardware (Mac or iDevices) or Apple software (OS X or iOS). As what they're looking for is related to their use of an Apple product, it's completely on topic.

While the FAQ says the questions must be about Apple hardware/software/other products or services, it doesn't say that it must *solely* be about them.

Now, given that, what kind of Apple-related questions would I take to SU? Probably ones along the lines of getting Ubuntu to play well with a Mac network, or an issue with something inside Windows running in VMWare. As those aren't primarily Apple-related questions, they could be seen as off-topic here.

Comment: Ah, I see the logic now. Thanks :-)